htacess rewrite directory inside directory
On my server the domain "domain.com" points to "/docroot/"
I would like to rewrite all requests from "domain.com/example1" to get files and directories located in:
"/docroot/example1/web/"
So if someone requests "domain.com/example1/image.jpg" they should get the file located in "/docroot/example1/web/image.jpg"
I have already done some research and came up with this:
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /example1/web/$1 [QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ web/ [L,QSA]
</IfModule>

The htaccess file is located in /docroot/example1/
As far as I can see this works BUT an issue arises whenever there is a directory of the same name inside of "web", like this: /docroot/example1/web/web/
If "domain.com/example1/web/image.jpg" is requested, I would want them to get "/docroot/example1/web/web/image.jpg".
However if the first "web"-directory already contains a file named "image.jpg" (so "/docroot/example1/web/image.jpg") then this file is served.
Does anyone have a solution or ideas?

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f is not fulfilled in this case. Not sure what you'd need this (and the following !-d condition) for at this level? You should probably rewrite to web first, and then if you need to give "missing" files or folders special treatment, do it from within there.

Thanks for the suggestion. Removing the mentioned RewriteCond results in the rewrite not working at all = Internal Server Error. The point of this directory structure is that it's "chrooted" - so other people can upload stuff to "web" (but not one directory up, where the htaccess resides), so I wouldn't want to do anything within "web" or below.

The internal server error is probably due to it "looping" and reaching the redirect limit. Ideally, what you are attempting to achieve here, would be achieved by a proper vhost setup to begin with, rather than via URL rewriting. (But I'm guessing this is on a cheap hosting platform, that doesn't allow for a proper setup?)

I am (or rather will be) able to edit virtual hosts files directly. However there will be multiple folders with the same setup, like this:
/docroot/example2/web/
/docroot/example3/web/
/docroot/example4/web/
and so on.

Would it not make more sense to do this the other way around then? /docroot/web/example1/, /docroot/web/example2/ etc. Then you can simply have domain.com pointing to /docroot/web/.

The issue is the "example" directories are for individual users (each with their own password), who will be able to upload files via SFTP.
user1 owns /example1. user2 owns /example2. and so on.
These users should not be able to see each each others files and directories.
So I have "chrooted" their base (home) folder = the respective "example" directories, meaning they won't be able to escape their base folder (which is not the same as the document root set in the virtual host config) and they will only be able to upload and edit everything below their own "web" directory.

For example: user1 connects via sftp and only sees what's in /docroot/example1/ and below. user1 is able to upload to /docroot/example1/web/. The URL domain.com/example1 rewrites this "web" directory, so anyone who requests domain.com/example1/image1.jpg gets the file located in /docroot/example1/web/
I am pretty sure you can do this with rewrites in htaccess, and other than the issue described in the OP it already works. However if rewriting doesn't work I may have no choice to change the whole setup as you suggested.

I don't think those RewriteConds checking for non-existing file/folder make much sense here to begin with. You should simply rewrite all incoming requests - something similar to this, https://serverfault.com/a/907902

Thanks, I remember I tried this before, now I tried it again and in order for it to work I had to remove the leading slash and enable FollowSymLinks, so the whole htaccess looks like this:
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> Options +FollowSymLinks RewriteEngine on RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$ RewriteRule (.*) web/$1 [L] </IfModule>
So far it's resisting any attempts to "break" it so it seems like this must be the solution.
